# MYSQL boolean types

Tags: mysql, boolean

Can someone confirm if what i think about boolean is right?

1. There is NO boolean type within tables. Instead, mysql use numeric types.
2. There IS boolean type within mysql program.

SO if you make a table with BOOL column, mysql will just use TINYINT(1) and you can insert TRUE or 1 that both will have the same result.

But if you use a operator or function that only accept boolean type as parameter like the operator "IS" ( IS boolean_value ) you HAVE TO use TRUE,FALSE (or even UNKNOWN)! you CAN NOT PASS 1 as an argument!

select 1 IS 1; #syntax error

select 1 IS TRUE; #return 1

is that right?

Comment: I almost never see `IS` being used in that manner in any of the RDBMSes I have worked with; most often I see `someFieldUsedForAFlagValue <> 0`.

Comment: Interesting. This is the first time I've seen any distinction between `TRUE` and `1`. Like @Uueerdo said, it's not very common anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes down to some definitions in the *sql standard*.

The sql standard defines a *truth value* as `TRUE | FALSE | UNKNOWN`.

The `IS`-operator is defined for the following two cases:

- A boolean test: `<boolean primary> [ IS [ NOT ] <truth value> ]` (a boolean primary is something that can be evaluated to a boolean)
- A test for the `null`-value: `<rowvalue> IS NULL`

So the correct syntax for `IS` requires it to be followed by either a *truth value* (so the words `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `UNKNOWN`), or `NULL`. E.g. `select 1 IS (1=1);` is not allowed either, because the result of `(1=1)` is a boolean, not a *truth value*.

This will be true for any database system that supports `IS` (if it does not want to violate the *sql standard*). So the reason you cannot use anything but one of the 4 words after `IS` is simply that the syntax forbids it, and is not yet an indication of how booleans are implemented. Because `IS` is optional in the boolean test, it's remaining main purpose is the test for the `null`-value, so apart from `IS NULL`, you usually don't ever need to use `IS`.

Generally, if a function requires a specific datatype (e.g. a boolean), you have to provide that datatype. But depending on the database system, there might be automatic type casting. And while some database systems do have seperate boolean datatypes, [MySQL implements `1 | 0 | null`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html) as the result of a boolean expression (which is by definition a boolean):

> In SQL, all logical operators evaluate to TRUE, FALSE, or NULL (UNKNOWN). In MySQL, these are implemented as 1 (TRUE), 0 (FALSE), and NULL. [...] MySQL evaluates any nonzero, non-NULL value to TRUE.

and uses this wherever booleans are used, e.g. [comparison operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html), and even casts it correctly if needed:

> Comparison operations result in a value of 1 (TRUE), 0 (FALSE), or NULL. These operations work for both numbers and strings. Strings are automatically converted to numbers and numbers to strings as necessary.

Consequential, for MySQL the [boolean datatype](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html) is a synonym for `TINYINT(1)`.

So if you can use `1` infront of `IS` (where a boolean expression is required) will depend on the database system. MySQL allows you to use `1`, PostgreSQL doesn't (but would allow `select (1=1) IS TRUE`), and MSSQL doesn't even support `IS`.

Comment: so this is all about syntax. there is no boolean type in mysql, instead they use number 1 0. is that right?

Comment: I added some details about this. Yes, there is no dedicated boolean type in MySQL tables, and yes, the result of a boolean expression, which is by definition a boolean, is implemented as numbers. It is interpretation if that means "there is no boolean type" in MySQL, as you just cannot distinguish it from numbers. For practical purposes you can probably say it that way, but in an exam or a theoretical discussion you should be aware of that distinction though.

Comment: Oh! I understand now! Thanks for the clear explanation! =D